# Rosdep installation failed during turtlebot installation

Tags: turtlebot, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm following the tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Installation to get my turtlebot up and running, and I'm running into a problem while I'm creating the turtlebot workspace. Here's the error message I get when running `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-indigo-create-dashboard]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-create-dashboard
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-indigo-create-dashboard] failed
```

What can I do about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198669/rosdep-installation-failed-during-turtlebot-installation/) by [Petya](https://answers.ros.org/users/20998/petya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The create_dashboard package was just released in the past few days, and hasn't been built and released to the public repository yet.

In the meantime, you can checkout the indigo branch of [turtlebot_create_desktop](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create_desktop/tree/indigo) into your workspace and build it from source.

The [turtlebot_create](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/tree/indigo) package was also released recently; if you have trouble with it, you may need it from source as well. Again, make sure you get the indigo branch and not the older hydro branch.

I'll try to update my answer once these packages make it to the public repository, and getting them from source is no longer required.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-12-02**:
rosinstall file used in the installation page has been updated. turtlebot_create_desktop should get installed with instruction from now.

https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_tools/commit/01d2dcc6f7d6c0d09bcb6cac9c7651a8738c9cf1